# Regex matching with positive lookhead

Tags: php, regex

I want to match `\''` in string `Apple MacBook Air 45\''` but my regex does not seem to work:

```
(?=[0-9]+)(\\'')
```

How to use possitive lookhead correctly? Or I need something else? I do not want to match using just `(\\'')` regex.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? The answer on this question is crucial in order to correctly answer your question.

Comment: I'm using PHP language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). In most flavors this can only be of fixed width, which should be sufficient:

`(?<=[0-9])\\''` or as php pattern: `$pattern = "/(?<=[0-9])\\\\''/";`

As you just want to check, if there is at least one `[0-9]` before `\''`.

See [test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mC9gY8/1)